# Trying to show products sold during peak hours

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to categorise products sold during peak order time. I have the Product and Quantity Ordered for the respective hour for 0-2300hrs

```
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns= ['Product', 'Hour', 'Quantity Ordered'])

df.sort_values(by=['Hour'], inplace=True)

sales_hour = df.groupby('Hour')
```

Am I correct to think the last line could group the data wrt to Hour? If yes, how would I display the Product and Quantity ordered wrt to the Hour?

I'm fairly new to python and stack overflow! Please let me know if my formatting is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO and congrats on your first question. Do share a sample of you data to enable us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. You could do this. Here is an example:

Assume you have the following df:

```
  Product            timestamp Pproperty  Quantity_ordered 
0  device_1  2020-12-04 05:15:00  cpu_5min                116
1  device_1  2020-12-04 05:30:00  cpu_5min                213
2  device_1  2020-12-04 05:35:00  cpu_5min                427
3  device_1  2020-12-04 05:15:00   vol_max                734
4  device_1  2020-12-04 05:30:00   vol_max                325
5  device_1  2020-12-04 05:35:00   vol_max                668
6  device_2  2020-12-04 05:15:00  cpu_5min                540
7  device_2  2020-12-04 05:30:00  cpu_5min                127
8  device_2  2020-12-04 05:35:00  cpu_5min                654
```

Then, do this:

```
df.sort_values(by=['timestamp'], inplace=True)

sales_hour = df.groupby('timestamp').sum().reset_index()
```

which returns

```
           timestamp  Quantity_ordered 
0  2020-12-04 05:15:00               1390
1  2020-12-04 05:30:00                665
2  2020-12-04 05:35:00               1749
```

But if you also want to group by products by hours, then do this:

```
df.sort_values(by=['timestamp'], inplace=True)

sales_hour = df.groupby(['timestamp','Product']).sum().reset_index()
```

which returns

```
            timestamp   Product  Quantity_ordered 
0  2020-12-04 05:15:00  device_1                850
1  2020-12-04 05:15:00  device_2                540
2  2020-12-04 05:30:00  device_1                538
3  2020-12-04 05:30:00  device_2                127
4  2020-12-04 05:35:00  device_1               1095
5  2020-12-04 05:35:00  device_2                654
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to use this for the above-mentioned problem and was able to play around with the data to get more results

Comment: If it is the answer you were afte, accept it so ir disappear from the unanswered question list.